# I merge two different payloads into one payload

Tags: json, mule, aggregation

I have two different payloads here in format:

```
{"addressLine1":"POSBUS 007","addressLine3":"-1","postalCode":"1200"}
{"email":"xxxx@xxx.net"}.
```

If I use the scatter gather i get the following payload:

```
[{"addressLine1":"POSBUS 007","addressLine3":"-1","postalCode":"1200"}, {"email":"xxxx@xxx.net"}]
```

But what I want to do is merge those two payloads into one payload like for instance:

```
  {"addressLine1":"POSBUS 007","addressLine3":"-1","postalCode":"1200", "email":"xxxx@xxx.net"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several good ways to solve this problem. Here's one using groovy:

1. In each route of the scatter-gather, add a `<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" />` to transform the JSON payload to a Map.
2. After the scatter-gather, add the following to transform the list of maps into a single map: `<set-payload value="#[groovy:payload.inject([:]) {result, part -> result.putAll(part); result}]" />`

Comment: These days I use dataweave, instead. :)