# Merging 2 JSON data into one generating exception

Tags: java, json, mule

I am stuck with a minor issue .. I have following Mule flow :-

```
<flow name="PostgresSQLFlow1" doc:name="PostgresSQLFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP" path="db"/>
        <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
            <processor-chain>
                <flow-ref name="PostgresSQLSub-Flow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
                <logger message="PostgresSql Done !!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </processor-chain>
            <processor-chain>
                <flow-ref name="MSSQLSub-Flow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
                <logger message="MSSQL Done !!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </scatter-gather>

        <set-payload value="....... Process Complete !!!! #[message.payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </flow>

    <sub-flow name="PostgresSQLSub-Flow" doc:name="PostgresSQLSub-Flow">
        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="Database_Global2" queryKey="RetriveQuery" queryTimeout="-1" doc:name="Database (JDBC)"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        <logger message="Postgres Data :- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="MSSQLSub-Flow" doc:name="MSSQLSub-Flow">
     <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="Database_Global" queryKey="RetriveQuery" queryTimeout="-1" doc:name="Database (JDBC)"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        <logger message="MSSQL Data :- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
   </sub-flow>
```

Now I am getting JSON Data from both the sub flow as the following :-

```
MSSQL Data :- [{"AGE":5,"DESIGNATION":"Software Engineer","NAME":"Sidray","ID":288},{"AGE":55,"DESIGNATION":"Software Engineer"}]
Postgres Data :- [{"AGE":33,"DESIGNATION":"Software Engineer","NAME":"Anil","ID":2}]
```

Now I want to merge it in a single JSON message ... 
I have tried the following :- In each subflow I used `<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" />` and then `I used <set-payload value="#[groovy:payload.inject([:]) {result, part -> result.putAll(part); result}]" />` 
I have taken the following as a reference :- [I merge two different payloads into one payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868364/i-merge-two-different-payloads-into-one-payload)
But no use .. I am getting the following exception :-

```
org.mule.routing.CompositeRoutingException: Exception was found for route(s): 0, 1. Message payload is of type: String
 at org.mule.routing.CollectAllAggregationStrategy.aggregateWithFailedRoutes(CollectAllAggregationStrategy.java:51)
 at org.mule.routing.CollectAllAggregationStrategy.aggregate(CollectAllAggregationStrategy.java:38)
 at org.mule.routing.ScatterGatherRouter.processResponses(ScatterGatherRouter.java:197)
  + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Please help how do I merge this 2 json data into one json ??

**UPDATED FLOW:-**

```
<flow name="PostgresSQLFlow1" doc:name="PostgresSQLFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP" path="db"/>
     <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
         <processor-chain>
            <flow-ref name="PostgresSQLSub-Flow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
            <logger message="PostgresSql Done !!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </processor-chain>
         <processor-chain>
          <flow-ref name="MSSQLSub-Flow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
            <logger message="MSSQL Done !!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </processor-chain>
     </scatter-gather>
  <set-payload value="#[groovy:payload.inject([:]) {result, part -> result.putAll(part); result}]" />

   </flow>

<sub-flow name="PostgresSQLSub-Flow" doc:name="PostgresSQLSub-Flow">
 <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="Database_Global2" queryKey="RetriveQuery" queryTimeout="-1" doc:name="Database (JDBC)"/>
 <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" />
   <logger message="Postgres Data :- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
 </sub-flow>

 <sub-flow name="MSSQLSub-Flow" doc:name="MSSQLSub-Flow">
 <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="Database_Global" queryKey="RetriveQuery" queryTimeout="-1" doc:name="Database (JDBC)"/>
 <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" />
 <logger message="MSSQL Data :- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

 </sub-flow>
```

Exception I am getting :-

```
INFO  2014-09-17 22:00:08,380 [[MultipleDBWithMSSQLAndPostgresSQL].ScatterGatherWorkManager.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'Database_Global2.dispatcher.1519448919'. Object is: EEJdbcMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-09-17 22:00:08,380 [[MultipleDBWithMSSQLAndPostgresSQL].ScatterGatherWorkManager.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'Database_Global.dispatcher.1649935156'. Object is: EEJdbcMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-09-17 22:00:08,381 [[MultipleDBWithMSSQLAndPostgresSQL].ScatterGatherWorkManager.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'Database_Global.dispatcher.1649935156'. Object is: EEJdbcMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-09-17 22:00:08,381 [[MultipleDBWithMSSQLAndPostgresSQL].ScatterGatherWorkManager.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'Database_Global2.dispatcher.1519448919'. Object is: EEJdbcMessageDispatcher
ERROR 2014-09-17 22:00:08,586 [[MultipleDBWithMSSQLAndPostgresSQL].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Exception was found for route(s): 0, 1. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Exception was found for route(s): 0, 1. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.routing.CompositeRoutingException)
  org.mule.routing.CollectAllAggregationStrategy:51 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/routing/CompositeRoutingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.routing.CompositeRoutingException: Exception was found for route(s): 0, 1. Message payload is of type: String
    at org.mule.routing.CollectAllAggregationStrategy.aggregateWithFailedRoutes(CollectAllAggregationStrategy.java:51)
    at org.mule.routing.CollectAllAggregationStrategy.aggregate(CollectAllAggregationStrategy.java:38)
    at org.mule.routing.ScatterGatherRouter.processResponses(ScatterGatherRouter.java:197)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Where did you put the merging logic? It seems it disrupts the `scatter-gather`.

Comment: I used json-to-object-transformer after object-to-json-transformer in each sub flow and then I used set-payload value="#[groovy:payload.inject([:]) {result, part -> result.putAll(part); result}]" after scatter and gather in PostgresSQLFlow1

Comment: Actually, why going from object to JSON then back to object? Why not just use the List of Maps returned by the JDBC endpoints?

Comment: Please check my updated flow

Comment: The JDBC endpoints produce Lists of Maps, not JSON strings so the `json-to-object-transformer` can't possibly work. Just remove them and let the `scatter-gather` provide you with the data from the JDBC endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JDBC endpoints produce Lists of Maps, not JSON strings so the json-to-object-transformer can't possibly work. Just remove them and let the scatter-gather provide you with the data from the JDBC endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

So, as per David's suggestion,final working code is :-

```
 <flow name="PostgresSQLFlow1" doc:name="PostgresSQLFlow1">
            <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP" path="db"/>
            <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
             <processor-chain>
               <flow-ref name="PostgresSQLSub-Flow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
                <logger message="PostgresSql Done !!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
               </processor-chain>
               <processor-chain>
                 <flow-ref name="MSSQLSub-Flow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
                 <logger message="MSSQL Done !!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
               </processor-chain>
            </scatter-gather>
           <set-payload value="....... Process Complete !!!! #[message.payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </flow>

        <sub-flow name="PostgresSQLSub-Flow" doc:name="PostgresSQLSub-Flow">
            <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="Database_Global2" queryKey="RetriveQuery" queryTimeout="-1" doc:name="Database (JDBC)"/>
            <logger message="Postgres Data :- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </sub-flow>
        <sub-flow name="MSSQLSub-Flow" doc:name="MSSQLSub-Flow">
         <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="Database_Global" queryKey="RetriveQuery" queryTimeout="-1" doc:name="Database (JDBC)"/>
          <logger message="MSSQL Data :- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
       </sub-flow>
```